# System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() +2725318

Tags: asp.net

i am getting an error while page reload on a dropdownlist option chang

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() +2725318
System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +61
System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +148

[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +206
System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +68
System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +8807191
System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +97
System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +63
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +133
```

I had found some articles saying if you increase the value of MaxHttpCollectionKeys in the app setting it will work but it doesn't seem to work for me
I have tried various different values extending to the below value but none work of

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="900000000000000000000000000000" />
```

you help is most appreciated

Comment: I have found a fix if you reduce the controls on the page the error stops comming...i had a gridview with 3000 item template populating on the page.i added paging now to the grid to show 8 line items and now the page works fine..Hope this helps.